# Memorizing the Keyboard

Tags: wordplay

I tried to type blindfolded,actually just closed my eyes and pressed the keyboard 
letters one by one with my index finger to write a song line that's on my mind. 
When I looked at the screen, I just misspelled all the words.All targets were 
miss hit one key away. Only the spacebar was pressed correctly every time. 
Can you guess what I tried to write? The screen output:

JB FUR H4VLHJJMT K JUX8BSFDW5KIX VYY MID UPC3 RIG UH. YB4 QLGC JX VP;S

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the D of MID? (I'm not particularly sure it's wrong, just a little surprised.)

Comment: Is every non-space character guaranteed to be wrong, or might it be just some of them?

Comment: D is a key off the target

Comment: The way my keyboard is laid out, I really don't think it quite is. I suppose it's a matter of definition, though.

Comment: QWERTY, I assume. This might be very different with, say a Dvorak layout.

Comment: Or a Colemak layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The song is

> *The Word* by the Beatles.

The lyrics go:

> In the beginning I misunderstood but now I've got it, the word is good